# Graph restarts after monitor change

Tags: c#, directshow, directshow.net, video-recording

I have a DirectShow graph which records and displays a video source. When I move **Video Renderer** window to other **monitor**, what I recorded gets deleted and recording starts again. I searched and found [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dfde2b75-6630-43e6-916b-8a7896290370/dragging-video-window-to-second-monitor-during-playback-crashes-player?forum=windowsdirectshowdevelopment) which says changing monitor stops and starts the graph. How can I stop the graph from being restarted? I don't want to lose my recording while switching between monitors.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The behavior you are describing is basically behavior by design (even though the side effect is pretty much annoying and confusing). Moving a video renderer between the monitors makes it re-allocate hardware resources used to present video, and this in turn needs a state transition. For recording, state transition means opening and closing the file.

Your solution is to either split into presentation and recording graphs, or to use custom allocator/presenter to take care of presentation yourself the way you want. Supposedly, graph splitting (what Wimmel suggests in another answer) is the preferable way adding other degrees of freedom in particular.

Comment: Will using Enhanced Video Renderer solve my problem? I don't want to split graphs. Thank you

Comment: Try it out, I am not sure. There is a chance EVR is OK: EVR allocates resources on all monitors at once and switches on the go, so it might not need to cause graph restarts.

Comment: EVR behaves as VR. My recorded file still stops and starts. If I understood correctly; video renderer sends EC_DISPLAY_CHANGED message to the graph and graph stops and then starts itself to match itself to the new monitor (because of possible resolution difference). Well, if I handle my graph's messages and drop EC_DISPLAY_CHANGED message, my graph won't restart. But it's the theory part. I don't know how to handle messages of graph.

Comment: Won't restart and won't show video on the new monitor.

Comment: Will not show the video? Oh, so handling the messages and events will not help me. Well, what's your suggestion Roman?

Comment: Video renderers restart graph for a reason, of course - this is how they switch resources. If you suppress the message/event used during this switch, then graph is not restarted, but VRs are unable to do what they needed to do... Split (bridge) graphs, this adds complexity, however this ends up as reliable and flexible solution.

Comment: Do you mean split via "Infinite Tee Filter" or "Smart Tee Filter"?

Comment: Neither of the two. You need video renderer and multiplexer/writer in separate filter graphs, so that one could restart without affecting the other. Read up on related details here: [GMFBridge - Multiple Graphs in DirectShow](http://www.gdcl.co.uk/gmfbridge/)

Comment: I embedded GMFBridge library to my application. Now my renderer filter is in separate graph which gets frames via GMFSourceFilter. The problem is: when I move window to another monitor, graph stops and doesn't start. Why graph doesn't start automatically? And how can I detect this situation and run graph again?

Comment: As I wrote, restart of the graph is required and is taking place automatically by default. Three is something in your scenario that prevents from it.

Comment: My graph captures frame from an analog PAL camera. The graph records video and delivers frames to BridgeSinkFilter using Infinite Tee filter to renderer. Since rendering graph is in second graph (BridgeSourceFilter), restarting renderer graph should not affect recording. But unfortunately renderer graph doesn't restart when I change renderer window's position to another monitor. It just stops and shows black screen (doesn't start again). Do you know why graph doesn't start after stopping? What can I do to start it again? Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

There is probably a good reason that the [EC_DISPLAY_CHANGED](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd319492%28VS.85%29.aspx) Message behaves that way, so I don't know what the disadvantages are when you handle this message yourself and don't restart the graph.

Instead you could separate the rendering graph from the recording using [GMFBridge](http://www.gdcl.co.uk/gmfbridge/index.htm). Use one graph to capture and record. Use the second graph only for rendering, so restarting that graph would not stop the recording.

**Edit**: Possibly you need to disconnect before the second graph is restarted. That will mean you do need to process the EC_DISPLAY_CHANGED message, even if you use GMFBridge.

```
m_pController->BridgeGraphs(NULL, NULL);
```

Comment: How can I handle EC_DISPLAY_CHANGED event and abort restarting the graph? I'll be happy if you help me little about this. Thank you

Comment: I never used this, but in the thread you linked to, it is suggested to use `IMediaEvent::CancelDefaultHandling` to receive that event. See also [Learning When an Event Occurs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390640%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).